# FPS style camera target calculation in XNA

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, math, xna, 3dcamera

What I need is to calculate where my lookat 3d vector would be based upon the camera position, the Y rotation and Z rotation, I would assume that any number greater than 0 would be sufficient for the distance from the camera to look at.

Here is the static class I'm using to control the camera and calculate the view and projection matrices, etc.

Class members that involve the position and rotation:

```
public static Vector3 Position { get; set; } //Publicly available for use outside the class
public static Vector3 Rotation { get; set; }
private static Vector3 camPos = new Vector3(0.0f, 200.0f, 300.0f); //However we work with these for manipulation of values
private static Vector3 camTarget = new Vector3(0, 0, -1200.0f);

private static float rotY = 0, rotZ = 0; //I believe that these are the correct axis following the right hand catasian coordinate system
```

My camera's update function:

```
public static void Update()        
{
    //Controls here

    //Update Position here
    Position = camPos;            

    //Update camTarget based on Position, rotY and rotZ <- Need help with this bit

    //After calculating camTarget update Rotation
    Rotation = camTarget;

    UpdateMatrices();
}
```

UpdateMatrices() handles everything else and works as it should but here it is just in case you would like to see it:

```
public static void UpdateMatrices()
{
    Matrix rotationMatrix = Matrix.CreateRotationX(MathHelper.ToRadians(90));
    Vector3 transformedReference = Vector3.Transform(Vector3.Forward, rotationMatrix);

    View = Matrix.CreateLookAt(Position, Rotation, Vector3.Forward);
    Projection = Matrix.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView(MathHelper.PiOver4, aspectRatio, nearClip, farClip);
    World = Matrix.Identity;

    CamBoundingFrustrum = new BoundingFrustum(View * Projection);
}
```

Would anyone be kind enough to share the secret to this please?

Comment: An important point that's not related to your question here: your `CamBoundingFrustrum` is a class, not a struct. This means that creating a 'new' one each frame makes a lot of garbage for the garbage collector. The intended way to process changes in the frustum each frame due to camera movements/rotations is to simply update (each frame) the `Matrix` property of the BoundingFrustum object that was created only once when the camera was initially created.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than using `Vector3.Forward`, pull the `.Forward` and `.Up` vectors from your rotation matrix:

```
    public void UpdateMatrices()
    {
        /// assumes Rotation is a Vector3 containing rotation around each axis expressed in radians
        Matrix rotationMatrix = Matrix.CreateFromYawPitchRoll(Rotation.Y, Rotation.X, Rotation.Z);
        /// View = Matrix.CreateLookAt(Position, Rotation, Vector3.Forward);

        View = Matrix.CreateLookAt(Position, Position + rotationMatrix.Forward, rotationMatrix.Up);
        Projection = Matrix.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView(MathHelper.PiOver4, aspectRatio, nearClip, farClip);

        /// World matrix needs to match your translation and rotation used above
        /// XNA expects matrices to be concatenated in SRT (scale, rotation, then translate) order:
        World = rotationMatrix * Matrix.CreateTranslation(Position);

        CamBoundingFrustrum = new BoundingFrustum(View * Projection);
    }
```

Note that you have to add the camera's translation (via a vector you're storing, or from the camera's world matrix `.Translation` property) to the `RotationMatrix.Forward` to get a real target.

The matrix `.Forward`, `.Backward`,`.Left`,`.Right`,`.Up` and `.Down` properties are the same as the equivalent `Vector3` properties transformed by the rotation matrix. so, `RotationMatrix.Forward` points in the direction you're looking, `.Up` is orthogonal to that, etc.

If you just use `Vector3.Forward`, you don't get a transformed vector, and weird things can happen.

Other notes:

1. Don't make everything static. Create an instance of your camera class during `Game.Initialize()` and add it as a property. `static` should be used with caution - it can cause all sorts of fun threading issues that will drive you insane.
2. I'd also recommend switching to a quaternion instead of yaw/roll/pitch (if you haven't already) since it avoids gimble lock, but that's a different topic.